# Ember Data: isDeleted has not changed on record but has changed in record.currentState

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, state, delete-record

Using Ember 1.3.0-beta.4 and Ember Data 1.0.0-beta.4.

I am attempting to delete a record with a simple `deleteRecord()` call.  However, when I fire `save()` on the record, it executes a `PUT` instead of a `DELETE`.

```
record.deleteRecord();
record.save();
```

Executes a `PUT`.

It turns out `isDeleted` is being improperly set somehow.  Or perhaps it is never changed.

```
record.get('isDeleted'); // false
record.get('isDirty');   // false
record.deleteRecord();
record.get('isDeleted'); // false
record.get('isDirty');   // true
```

However the `currentState` DOES appear to have changed.

```
record.deleteRecord();
record.get('isDeleted');              // false
record.get('currentState.isDeleted'); // true
record.get('currentState.stateName'); // "root.deleted.uncommitted"
```

Other records delete as normal. Rarely (1 in 10) this code behaves as expected which leads me to believe this is a sequencing issue.

Is there any reason, deleting a record would behave this way?

Comment: Can you reproduce in a jsbin? here's a simple example that works http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/107/edit

Comment: Well I didnt know that you could set `{async:true}` on a `belongsTo`.  Do you have some good documentation on that I could look at? Perhaps thats it.

Comment: I'm not even using the async relationship :)  There isn't a ton of documentation on it since the implementation is still hardening, https://github.com/emberjs/website/blob/master/source/guides/models/the-rest-adapter.md

Comment: So I found out what the `async: true` does.  Essentially it returns a promise instead of the resulting value.  Pretty neat!